# GetComponentInChildren with child index when there are multiple child objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I select from which child I want to get a component from using `.GetComponentInChildren` when I have multiple child objects?

With this code I get the `MeshRenderer` of the first child only.

```
 selectedObj.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
```

Comment: You could have a reference to the specific child you'd like to edit the material of? Other than that, if you'd like to change more than one child you could have a script inside the ones you'll need to edit and get that component and then from that script edit the material.

Comment: Do you know the name of the child object you want to get the component from at run time?  Is it a unique name?

Comment: I know the name of the child at run time. I am trying to find the best way to do it. I have one script in TileManager which handles pretty much everything and one script in Tile which have some variables and this  `void OnMouseDown () {
  
  //Let Tiles Manager know that there was a press on (this) Tile
  tilesManager.OnObjectSelection(this.gameObject);
 }`

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/60c7b080661247bd8c9ad053a9170a7d.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the unique name of the child object that has the component you are after, you can use `transform.FindChild("nameOfChildObject")` to find the specific child object you are looking for.  So in your case you could say:

```
selectedObject.transform.FindChild("nameOfChildObject").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that pretty much does what i wanted with one line of code.

Answer (score 4):

`GetComponentInChildren` cannot do this. You can do that with the index of the child GameObject with the help of the `GetChild` function. The code below will get component of a child GameObject with the index of 3.

```
int CHILD_INDEX = 3;
selectedObj.transform.GetChild(CHILD_INDEX).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
```

Make custom generic extension method for this and add index parameter to the `GetComponentInChildren` function:

```
public static class ExtensionFunction
{
    public static T GetComponentInChildren<T>(this GameObject gameObject, int index)
    {
        return gameObject.transform.GetChild(index).GetComponent<T>();
    }
}
```

Then you can now do:

```
int CHILD_INDEX = 3;
selectedObj.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>(CHILD_INDEX).material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
```

Using `FindChild` each time you just want to get component from a child GameObject will only slow down your game especially if you do a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your help too but James Hogle answer does exactly what i want with just one line of code. Although your code might be better for more complex algorithms.

Comment: Actually if you need to do this more than once, the second (third..) time will be just one more line of code! Anyway, using index is better more robust method to learn and get into good habits I think, I put a comment next to my line to say eg child 0 should be (object name) "xxx" child 1 should be "yyy" then easier someone else to understand quickly. or if someone changes it quicker to see problem perhaps, it's about doing it right at beginning before code gets massive.  Actually I'm surprised Unity doesn't just put this extension function inbuilt, would be commonly used I imagine.

Comment: @WillCroxford Yes, I think this function should be built in into Unity or included as a helper function. Unfortunately, I think Unity will do whatever they like. They don't  listen much when it comes to feature request.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
MeshRenderer[] var = selectedObj.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>;
foreach (material m in var)
{
   m.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
}
```

Then i just loop var to modify each object.